# Converting Text into an Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, formatting, format

I have been developing a program that reads a text  from a text file. After reading the text, I want to convert the text to an image but with random attributes such as font style, size and more. The thing is the output image should not exceed  `700(image_width)` and `100(image_height)`. When the chosen random font is large, the text dimension exceeds the limit (horizontally and vertically).

What I want is to adjust the paragraph width so that it can fit horizontally and when it exceeds vertically, just include those text that can be fitted in the height limit.

What my current code does is when the text size exceeds, it chooses another random smaller font so that it will not exceed the dimension limit. This is not what I want since it will only reproduce text with small fonts.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

from random import seed
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import os.path

#Constant dimensions of the image.
image_width = 700
image_height = 1000

#Returns the text size in terms of width and height.
def getSize(txt, font):
    testImg = Image.new('RGB', (1, 1))
    testDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(testImg)
    return testDraw.textsize(txt, font)

#Randomize XY coordinate of the text in white background image.
def get_xy_coordinates(text, font):    
    width, height = getSize(text, font)    
    xy = (randint(1, image_width  - width), randint(1, image_height - height ))
    return xy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    seed()
    file_counter = 1


    fonts = ['arial.ttf', 'arialbd.ttf', 'arialbi.ttf', 'ariali.ttf', 'ARIALN.TTF', 'ARIALNB.TTF', 'ARIALNBI.TTF', 'ARIALNI.TTF','ariblk.ttf','ARLRDBD.TTF','georgia.ttf','georgiab.ttf','georgiai.ttf','georgiaz.ttf','GRGAREF.TTF','OCRAEXT.TTF','OCRAStd.otf', 'times.ttf','timesbd.ttf','timesbi.ttf','timesi.ttf','verdana.ttf','verdanab.ttf','verdanai.ttf','verdanaz.ttf', 'VERDREF.TTF']

    while True:


        print(file_counter)

        if not os.path.isfile('text/' + str (file_counter) + '.txt'):
            break

        text = open('text/' + str (file_counter) + ".txt", encoding="utf8")

        text = text.read()
        font_number = randint(0,25)

        fontname = 'fonts/' + fonts[font_number]        

        #Limits text dimension to constant maximum dimensions of training and testing images.
        while True:
            fontsize = randint(10, 50)         
            font = ImageFont.truetype(fontname, fontsize)
            width, height = getSize(text, font)
            if (width < image_width) and (height < image_height):
                break

        #Creates an image with white background of constant size.
        img = Image.new('RGB', (image_width, image_height), 'white')
        d = ImageDraw.Draw( img)           
        #d.text(get_xy_coordinates(text, font), text, fill='black', font=font)             
        img.save("text_images/" + str(file_counter) + ".png")
        file_counter = file_counter + 1
```

Notes:

[Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VPaeTrrtJT2c8LhST0yX-ksrF9VAagPP) for the text files used.

[Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ui5ug8krINcjVF84Kpf7zimQyhcG-Ywy) for the font files used.

Note : Text files content varies. Some contains few words, some are many. I dont want to distort the text's width and height aspect ratio.

Comment: Could you try rendering the image regardless of the format and then compressing it to your max dimension for whichever dimension is over the limit? Not sure if that's a constraint or unacceptable. Just need a starting point.

Comment: @zerecees -> Thank you but I dont want to distort in any way the text width and height aspect ratio.

Comment: Gotcha. You could adjust the width/height of the image proportionally so it keeps the aspect ratio. But, I'm assuming that wont work either. Are you essentially trying to create a word cloud?